# Can AVPlayer play MP3 files on iPad

Tags: iphone

Can AVPlayer place MP3 files?

It does not list MP3 in the apple documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can play MP3.

Try reading the [apple documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6) and specifically the section entitled "iOS Hardware and Software Audio Codecs"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Did u try using

```
   [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl error:nil];
```

to play the file

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete sample.

myClass.h:

```
- @interface myClass : NSObject \<AVAudioPlayerDelegate\> ...
```

myClass.m:

```
   localPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
   initWithContentsOfURL:newAudioURL error:nil]; [localPlayer
   setDelegate:self];

   - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)playedPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag {
        NSLog(@"releasing");
        [playedPlayer release];
        NSLog(@"released"); }
```